# Two startup daemon processes working together in wsl2?

Tags: services, windows-subsystem-for-linux, process, top

[image]

We normally know that WSL2 normally do not have systemd it generally starts on init daemon! But recently from year 2022 we can also use systemd by enabling the sysboot to systemd in wsl.config.
So I did that and after starting dbus service and rebooting systemd was enabled! But when I now run top command I see both init and systemd ! So I am having conufsions because I was taught pid 1 is the startup process and it can be either systemd or init! how both are existing I don't understand! Can anyone clarify me?

Comment: Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: actually in those case, the image might be the 'right' thing - I've uploaded the image to imgur and inlined the image as we do things here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [How is this change possible in WSL?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/#how-is-this-change-possible-in-wsl) in [Microsoft Developer Blogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/), that's because the regular WSL `init` process is started as a child process of `systemd` to provide existing WSL functionality:

> Supporting systemd required changes to the WSL architecture. As
> systemd requires PID 1, the WSL init process started within the Linux
> distribution becomes a child process of the systemd. Because the WSL
> init process is responsible for providing the infrastructure for
> communication between the Linux and Windows components, changing this
> hierarchy required rethinking some of the assumptions made with the
> WSL init process.

Comment: Thanks ❤️‍ brother for your help now its clear!